# Render React Native Elements from JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I have searched around...can't quite find what I'm looking for, so I appreciate any help! Here is what I am going for:

I am building a CMS-like setup for a React Native app. This is so that an admin of an app can login to the CMS dashboard, and update a page/view of the app without having to go into the hardcode. I would like them to be able to choose from a pre-set list of components and be able to drag-and-drop them into the app, in whatever order they would want and be able to update the content and colors, etc. Let me provide an example...

There is a home page that I imagine having a rotating banner at the top, then a button for a information modal, then a set of menu links to go to sub-child pages.

So what I think, development-wise, is to give the app admin a WYSIWYG type of setup, and to store the result of this in the Database. It could store in the database as:

```
<RotatingBanner />
<Modal />
<ContentMenu>
    <ContentMenuLink title="About" />
    <ContentMenuLink title="Competitive" />
    <ContentMenuLink title="Recreational" />
    <ContentMenuLink title="Tournaments" />
<ContentMenu />
```

Right now, when I try to render this into a screen, I continue to have it render that as the actual words vs the components they are representing if that makes sense. So the page looks just like the code block above, instead of seeing a rotating banner and modal, etc.

I have tried a tool to convert HTML into React Native elements...does anyone know how I can convert a fetched JSON that would look like:

```
{content: "<RotatingBanner /><Modal /><ContentMenu>...."}
```

and have it create the real components in the render function? Any other thoughts or ideas/advice on creating a CMS like this are greatly appreciated if you would like.

Thanks!

Comment: So what you basically need is a json controlled view right? You can simply achieve such need by creating components first. Like content menu, rotationg banner etc. and then just render them with a map function.
` return this.jsonResponseElementsArray.map((value, index)=>{
    switch(value) {
        case 'rotatingBanner':
             return <RotatingBanner />
    }
});`

I can't be sure if this is what you want. Let me know if I may help you further

Comment: Thanks for the input...yes, the idea would be to have previously created the components already. Then in the admin CMS area, the admin could simply select and re-order them how they see fit, and then submit it. This would submit it to the database as my example "content" in the JSON I gave in question. The part I am confused on is how to render that content. You gave example of "this.jsonResponseElementsArray.map.......". I will have to try this and see how it functions, but it would seem that I have to make it realize the "value" is each element

Comment: I mean AFAIK, you cant render Views and Texts from a json request. You should explicitly tell the content when coding. For my example each value is just a string of a specific component. Nothing more. More like a map

Comment: Gotcha...well I guess my base question is how to render it from the JSON request. I  guess I  will have to keep thinking on how to make this RN CMS. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your have this JSON:

```js
const data = {
  "components": [
    {"name": "component1", props: {"hello": "world"}},
    {"name": "component2", props: {"color": "red"}},
  ]
}
```

Make your components and then reference them in an Object (map):

```jsx
import Component1 from './Component1'
import Component2 from './Component2'

const COMPONENT_MAP = {
  component1: Component1,
  component2: Component2,
}
```

Then make your wrapper component:

```jsx
const Wrapper = ({data}) => (
  <View>
    {data.components.map(({name, props}) => {
      const Component = COMPONENT_MAP[name]
      return <Component {...props} />
    }}
  </View>
)
```

Voilà :)

```jsx
<Wrapper data={data} />
```

Comment: Thanks @antoine129 l. I don't this this addresses the specific use case where `data = { components: [ "<RotatingBanner /><Modal />" ] }`

Comment: Indeed, but addressing this use case would require JSX parsing and I recommend against that.

Comment: I don't think this answers the original use case, but I'll give the bounty, as at least you're suggesting the ideal scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Array's to save and render multiple childrens

```
const Component1 = () => <Text>One</Text>
const Component2 = () => <Text>One</Text>

const childs = [
  Component1,
  Component2
]
return childs
```

React is able to render arrays as they are.
Other possible solution could be,

```
return Object.keys(child).map(item => childs[item] )
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution can be [`react-native-dynamic-render`](https://github.com/moh3n9595/react-native-dynamic-render)

Also, you can render nested components with that.

A complete example is [here](https://snack.expo.io/@moh3n95/react-native-dynamic-render)